# Memory Management - Objective C NSString

Tags: objective-c, memory, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary called "output" and I am adding an NSString into it that is an integer. What is the proper way to do this? I can't figure it out. Everything I've tried ends up giving memory leaks.

This is what I currently have:

val is an int

countryName is an NSString

Here is how I declare "output":

```
NSMutableDictionary *output = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Here is the code that causes a memory leak:

```
NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",val];
[output setValue:temp forKey:countryName];
```

The following also causes a leak:

```
 NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i",val];
 [output setValue:temp forKey:source];
 [temp release];
```

Comment: What you posted looks fine. Why do you think you have memory leaks and which object(s) do you believe you are leaking?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using `%d` instead of `%i`?

Comment: I ran the application in Instruments and it showed I had a 100% memory leak on that line.

Comment: As an aside, don't use `setValue:forKey:` to add objects to a dictionary, use `setObject:forKey:`  The former is for key value coding, has slightly different semantics and is a little bit slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to print temp variable like this

`NSLog("number = %d", [temp intValue]);`

to check that the temp variable is storing the integer variable or not.

you can also post the code the you used to declare the NSMutableDictionary may be we can find some sort of declaration problem there.

Comment: Here is the declaration of "output":  NSMutableDictionary *output = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];

Comment: and here is the code that gets a 100% memory leak:    NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",val];
   [output setValue:temp forKey:keywordName];

Comment: You can also autorelease it before you are returning the object in objective - c

Comment: well you can use alloc and initWithFormat: to initialize temp and then release the object after the  [output setValue:temp forKey:countryName]; statement.

Comment: there is still a leak when I use initWithFormat...see above. I posted the code.

Comment: i am not sure about it but place a break point after the releasing the temp variable and just move your cursor on the temp to check what is its summary.  If its showing you anything other than 'out of scope' than it means that you are retain it again in your code. Try accessing the temp variable in nslog to check whether the app receives a exc_bad_access

Answer (score 2):

instruments points you to the source of the leaked object's creation. your code snippet is fine. this implies that later on you access the value from output (or temp itself) and over-retain from that site.

Comment: I am returning "output" but what do you mean over-retain from that site?

Comment: it means that (the most common example) you access the key:`countryName` from the result of the function/method (aka `output`, which you return). the section of code which accesses the value for countryName then introduces an imbalance in the reference count by messaging `retain` where it does not need to be retained.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a copy of the value and then return setValue to mutable dictionary. Then release it.

```
NSMutableDictionary *copyOfItem = [item copy];
[tmpMarkers addObject: copyOfItem];
[copyOfItem release], copyOfItem = nil;
```